# What's the best forum resource for Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In the past I've used RailsForum.com as a resource, but lately I've come across far too much spam and not enough useful posting.  Certainly just my perspective.

So, what do you Rails developers use as a forum resource for the platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official [Ruby On Rails Talk](http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-talk) mailing list is a good spot for discussion.  I also tend to go to `#rubyonrails` irc channel on irc.freenode.net with my questions.  There tend to be lots of helpful folks there.

Answer (score 6):

Use stackoverflow. I've stopped using all the email lists and forums I used to need. This site has reached critical mass so unless your dealing with some really obscure technology I find I get answers quicker here then anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

I've never had a problem with railsforum.com, but I tend to just google keywords for any questions I have. There is a lot of online Rails documentation, and this system tends to produce decent results.

Also, consider browsing the Rails api when you have issues. I've found that there's a lot more data there that I'm aware of, and many of my problems are solved before they even develop when I do this frequently.